# Repeated measure ANOVA (rANOVA) by MATLAB

Tags: matlab, model, anova

I have 3 groups of individuals ( young (n=10), middle age (n=9), old (n=13)) in each participant 6 parameters are measured. Here is the list:

1) Heart_rate_at_rest ( block 1)
2) Heart_rate_at rest (block2)

3) Hear_rate_ after_run ( block1)
4) Heart_rate_after_run ( block2)

5) age

6) Blood pressure

I made a table of the data as below:

```
  t=table(groups,meas(:,1),meas(:,2),meas(:,3),meas(:,4),meas(:,5),meas(:,6),   ...,'VariableNames, 
{'groups','meas1','meas2','meas3','meas4','meas5','meas6'});

Meas = table([1 2 3 4 5 6]','VariableNames',{'Measurements'});
```

and I feed it to fitrm command to make a model

```
 rm = fitrm(t,'meas1-meas6~groups','WithinDesign',Meas);
```

and run RANOVA

```
   ranovatbl = ranova(rm)
```

It gives me table below

[image]

I have the few questions below:

1) how can I make the command fitrm understand that parameters 1 and 2 or 3 or 4 are interrelated?

2) how can I make the model understand that I would like o see if there is any significance between (1), (2) and (3), (4) while it is important to know if there is any relationship between (1) and (2) or (3) and (4) ?

3) which one of the 4 p-values from the table is more important? ( there are 4 p-values) what does this p-value in this  "contenxt" mean? how can I realize the reported p-value means significance of which of the measures in the table with the other ones?

Thank you